# Buildozer 0.32 fails to build

Tags: android, python, kivy, buildozer

After downloading the official Buildozer VM from the kivy project (https://kivy.org/#download)and updating it like in the README of the VM suggested (https://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-android-vm.html#kivy-android-vm). I tried to build with `buildozer android_new debug`
After fixing several missing dependencies, I'm running in to an unintelligible error:

```
[INFO]:    Unpacking sdl2_image for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/release/SDL2_image-2.0.1.tar.gz
[INFO]:    -> directory context /media/sf_PycharmProjects/settings/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/bootstrap_builds/sdl2-python2/jni
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/media/sf_PycharmProjects/settings/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-master/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 837, in <module>
    main()
  File "/media/sf_PycharmProjects/settings/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-master/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 834, in main
    ToolchainCL()
  File "/media/sf_PycharmProjects/settings/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-master/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 489, in __init__
    getattr(self, args.subparser_name.replace('-', '_'))(args)
  File "/media/sf_PycharmProjects/settings/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-master/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 147, in wrapper_func
    build_dist_from_args(ctx, dist, args)
  File "/media/sf_PycharmProjects/settings/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-master/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 190, in build_dist_from_args
    build_recipes(build_order, python_modules, ctx)
  File "pythonforandroid/build.py", line 548, in build_recipes
  File "pythonforandroid/recipe.py", line 542, in prepare_build_dir
  File "pythonforandroid/recipe.py", line 444, in unpack
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 1021, in __call__
    return RunningCommand(cmd, call_args, stdin, stdout, stderr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 486, in __init__
    self.wait()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 500, in wait
    self.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 516, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc(self.ran, self.process.stdout, self.process.stderr)
sh.ErrorReturnCode_2
# Command failed: python -m pythonforandroid.toolchain --color=always --storage-dir=/media/sf_PycharmProjects/settings/.buildozer/android/platform/build create --dist_name=myapp --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=kivy --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs
```

Any ideas what is missing?

Full Debug Output:

```
kivy@kivy-VirtualBox:/media/sf_PycharmProjects/settings$ buildozer android_new debug
# Check configuration tokens
# Ensure build layout
# Check configuration tokens
# Preparing build
# Check requirements for android
# Run 'dpkg --version'
# Cwd None
Debian `dpkg' package management program version 1.17.5 (amd64).
This is free software; see the GNU General Public License version 2 or
later for copying conditions. There is NO warranty.
# Search for Git (git)
#  -> found at /usr/bin/git
# Search for Cython (cython)
#  -> found at /usr/local/bin/cython
# Search for Java compiler (javac)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac
# Search for Java keytool (keytool)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/keytool
# Install platform
# Apache ANT found at /home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4
# Android SDK found at /home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-20
# Android NDK found at /home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c
# Check application requirements
# Check garden requirements
# Compile platform
# Run 'python -m pythonforandroid.toolchain --color=always --storage-dir=/media/sf_PycharmProjects/settings/.buildozer/android/platform/build create --dist_name=myapp --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=kivy --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs'
# Cwd /media/sf_PycharmProjects/settings/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-master
[INFO]:    Will compile for the following archs: armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    Found Android API target in $ANDROIDAPI
[INFO]:    Available Android APIs are (19)
[INFO]:    Requested API target 19 is available, continuing.
[INFO]:    Found NDK dir in $ANDROIDNDK
[INFO]:    Got NDK version from $ANDROIDNDKVER
[INFO]:    Using Google NDK r9c
[INFO]:    Found virtualenv at /usr/local/bin/virtualenv
[INFO]:    ccache is missing, the build will not be optimized in the future.
[INFO]:    Found the following toolchain versions: ['4.6', '4.8', 'clang3.3']
[INFO]:    Picking the latest gcc toolchain, here 4.8
[INFO]:    No existing dists meet the given requirements!
[INFO]:    No dist exists that meets your requirements, so one will be built.
[INFO]:    Bootstrap requires recipes ['sdl2', ('python2', 'python3crystax')]
[INFO]:    Loaded recipe sdl2 (depends on [('python2', 'python3crystax'), 'sdl2_image', 'sdl2_mixer', 'sdl2_ttf'], conflicts ['sdl', 'pygame', 'pygame_bootstrap_components'])
[INFO]:    Loaded recipe kivy (depends on ['pyjnius', ('sdl2', 'pygame'), ('python2', 'python3crystax')])
[INFO]:    Loaded recipe sdl2_image (depends on [])
[INFO]:    Loaded recipe sdl2_mixer (depends on [])
[INFO]:    Loaded recipe sdl2_ttf (depends on [])
[INFO]:    Loaded recipe pyjnius (depends on ['six', ('sdl2', 'sdl', 'genericndkbuild'), ('python2', 'python3crystax')])
[INFO]:    Loaded recipe six (depends on [('python2', 'python3crystax')])
[INFO]:    Found multiple valid recipe sets:
[INFO]:        ['six', 'sdl2', u'kivy', 'sdl2_ttf', 'sdl2_mixer', 'sdl2_image', 'pyjnius', 'python2']
[INFO]:        ['sdl2', 'six', 'sdl2_ttf', 'python3crystax', 'sdl2_mixer', 'sdl2_image', 'pyjnius', u'kivy']
[INFO]:    Using the first of these: ['six', 'sdl2', u'kivy', 'sdl2_ttf', 'sdl2_mixer', 'sdl2_image', 'pyjnius', 'python2']
[INFO]:    The selected bootstrap is sdl2
[INFO]:    # Creating dist with sdl2 bootstrap
[INFO]:    Dist will have name myapp and recipes (kivy)
[INFO]:    -> running cp -r /media/sf_PycharmProjects/settings/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-master/pythonforandroid/bootstraps/sdl2/build /media/sf_PycharmProjects/settings/.buildozer/android...(and 51 more)
[INFO]:    -> directory context /media/sf_PycharmProjects/settings/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/bootstrap_builds/sdl2-python2
[INFO]:    <- directory context /media/sf_PycharmProjects/settings/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-master
[INFO]:    Recipe build order is ['python2', 'sdl2_image', 'sdl2_mixer', 'sdl2_ttf', 'sdl2', 'six', 'pyjnius', u'kivy']
[INFO]:    # Downloading recipes 
[INFO]:    Downloading python2
[INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /media/sf_PycharmProjects/settings/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/python2
[INFO]:    -> directory context /media/sf_PycharmProjects/settings/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/python2
[INFO]:    -> running basename http://python.org/ftp/python/2.7.2/Python-2.7.2.tar.bz2
[WARNING]: Should check headers here! Skipping for now.
[INFO]:    -> running rm -f .mark-Python-2.7.2.tar.bz2
[INFO]:    Downloading python2 from http://python.org/ftp/python/2.7.2/Python-2.7.2.tar.bz2
Downloading python2 from http://python.org/ftp/python/2.7.2/Python-2.7.2.tar.bz2                                                                                                                                                            
- Do[INFO]:    -> running touch .mark-Python-2.7.2.tar.bz2
[INFO]:    <- directory context /media/sf_PycharmProjects/settings/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-master
[INFO]:    Downloading sdl2_image
[INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /media/sf_PycharmProjects/settings/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/sdl2_image
[INFO]:    -> directory context /media/sf_PycharmProjects/settings/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/sdl2_image
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/release/SDL2_image-2.0.1.tar.gz
[WARNING]: Should check headers here! Skipping for now.
[INFO]:    -> running rm -f .mark-SDL2_image-2.0.1.tar.gz
[INFO]:    Downloading sdl2_image from https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/release/SDL2_image-2.0.1.tar.gz
Downloading sdl2_image from https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/release/SDL2_image-2.0.1.tar.gz                                                                                                                                       
- Download[INFO]:    -> running touch .mark-SDL2_image-2.0.1.tar.gz
[INFO]:    <- directory context /media/sf_PycharmProjects/settings/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-master
[INFO]:    Downloading sdl2_mixer
[INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /media/sf_PycharmProjects/settings/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/sdl2_mixer
[INFO]:    -> directory context /media/sf_PycharmProjects/settings/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/sdl2_mixer
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_mixer/release/SDL2_mixer-2.0.1.tar.gz
                                                                                                       [WARNING]: Should check headers here! Skipping for now.                                                                              
[INFO]:    -> running rm -f .mark-SDL2_mixer-2.0.1.tar.gz
[INFO]:    Downloading sdl2_mixer from https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_mixer/release/SDL2_mixer-2.0.1.tar.gz
Downloading sdl2_mixer from https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_mixer/release/SDL2_mixer-2.0.1.tar.gz                                
- Download [INFO]:    -> running touch .mark-SDL2_mixer-2.0.1.tar.gz
[INFO]:    <- directory context /media/sf_PycharmProjects/settings/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-master
[INFO]:    Downloading sdl2_ttf
[INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /media/sf_PycharmProjects/settings/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/sdl2_ttf
[INFO]:    -> directory context /media/sf_PycharmProjects/settings/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/sdl2_ttf
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/release/SDL2_ttf-2.0.14.tar.gz
           working: SDL2_ttf-2.0.14.tar.gz                                                                                                                                             [WARNING]: Should check headers here! Skipping for now.
[INFO]:    -> running rm -f .mark-SDL2_ttf-2.0.14.tar.gz
[INFO]:    Downloading sdl2_ttf from https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/release/SDL2_ttf-2.0.14.tar.gz
Downloading sdl2_ttf from https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/release/SDL2_ttf-2.0.14.tar.gz                                                                                                                                            
- Download 90.27%[INFO]:    -> running touch .mark-SDL2_ttf-2.0.14.tar.gz
[INFO]:    <- directory context /media/sf_PycharmProjects/settings/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-master
[INFO]:    Downloading sdl2
[INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /media/sf_PycharmProjects/settings/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/sdl2
[INFO]:    -> directory context /media/sf_PycharmProjects/settings/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/sdl2
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL2-2.0.4.tar.gz
           working: SDL2-2.0.4.tar.gz                                                                                [WARNING]: Should check headers here! Skipping for now.
[INFO]:    -> running rm -f .mark-SDL2-2.0.4.tar.gz
[INFO]:    Downloading sdl2 from https://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL2-2.0.4.tar.gz
Downloading sdl2 from https://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL2-2.0.4.tar.gz                                                                                                                                                                      
- Download 90.51%[INFO]:    -> running touch .mark-SDL2-2.0.4.tar.gz
[INFO]:    <- directory context /media/sf_PycharmProjects/settings/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-master
[INFO]:    Downloading six
[INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /media/sf_PycharmProjects/settings/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/six
[INFO]:    -> directory context /media/sf_PycharmProjects/settings/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/six
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/six/six-1.9.0.tar.gz
           working: six-1.9.0.tar.gz                                                                                                                     [WARNING]: Should check headers here! Skipping for now.
[INFO]:    -> running rm -f .mark-six-1.9.0.tar.gz
[INFO]:    Downloading six from https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/six/six-1.9.0.tar.gz
Downloading six from https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/six/six-1.9.0.tar.gz                                                                                                                                                         
[INFO]:    -> running touch .mark-six-1.9.0.tar.gz
[INFO]:    <- directory context /media/sf_PycharmProjects/settings/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-master
[INFO]:    Downloading pyjnius
[INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /media/sf_PycharmProjects/settings/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/pyjnius
[INFO]:    -> directory context /media/sf_PycharmProjects/settings/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/pyjnius
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://github.com/kivy/pyjnius/archive/master.zip
[WARNING]: Should check headers here! Skipping for now.
[INFO]:    -> running rm -f .mark-master.zip
[INFO]:    Downloading pyjnius from https://github.com/kivy/pyjnius/archive/master.zip
Downloading pyjnius from https://github.com/kivy/pyjnius/archive/master.zip                                                                                                                                                                 
[INFO]:    -> running touch .mark-master.zip
[INFO]:    <- directory context /media/sf_PycharmProjects/settings/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-master
[INFO]:    Downloading kivy
[INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /media/sf_PycharmProjects/settings/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/kivy
[INFO]:    -> directory context /media/sf_PycharmProjects/settings/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/kivy
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://github.com/kivy/kivy/archive/master.zip
[WARNING]: Should check headers here! Skipping for now.
[INFO]:    -> running rm -f .mark-master.zip
[INFO]:    Downloading kivy from https://github.com/kivy/kivy/archive/master.zip
Downloading kivy from https://github.com/kivy/kivy/archive/master.zip                                                                                                                                                                       
- Down[INFO]:    -> running touch .mark-master.zip
[INFO]:    <- directory context /media/sf_PycharmProjects/settings/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-master
[INFO]:    # Building all recipes for arch armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    # Unpacking recipes
[INFO]:    Unpacking python2 for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    -> running basename http://python.org/ftp/python/2.7.2/Python-2.7.2.tar.bz2
                                                                                                                     [INFO]:    -> directory context /media/sf_PycharmProjects/settings/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/python2/armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    -> running tar tf /media/sf_PycharmProjects/settings/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/python2/Python-2.7.2.tar.bz2
           working: Python-2.7.2/Mac/Demo/sound/morse.py                                                                                              [INFO]:    -> running mv Python-2.7.2 /media/sf_PycharmProjects/settings/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/python2/armeabi-v7a/python2
[INFO]:    <- directory context /media/sf_PycharmProjects/settings/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-master
[INFO]:    Unpacking sdl2_image for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/release/SDL2_image-2.0.1.tar.gz
[INFO]:    -> directory context /media/sf_PycharmProjects/settings/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/bootstrap_builds/sdl2-python2/jni
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/media/sf_PycharmProjects/settings/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-master/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 837, in <module>
    main()
  File "/media/sf_PycharmProjects/settings/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-master/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 834, in main
    ToolchainCL()
  File "/media/sf_PycharmProjects/settings/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-master/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 489, in __init__
    getattr(self, args.subparser_name.replace('-', '_'))(args)
  File "/media/sf_PycharmProjects/settings/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-master/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 147, in wrapper_func
    build_dist_from_args(ctx, dist, args)
  File "/media/sf_PycharmProjects/settings/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-master/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 190, in build_dist_from_args
    build_recipes(build_order, python_modules, ctx)
  File "pythonforandroid/build.py", line 548, in build_recipes
  File "pythonforandroid/recipe.py", line 542, in prepare_build_dir
  File "pythonforandroid/recipe.py", line 444, in unpack
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 1021, in __call__
    return RunningCommand(cmd, call_args, stdin, stdout, stderr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 486, in __init__
    self.wait()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 500, in wait
    self.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 516, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc(self.ran, self.process.stdout, self.process.stderr)
sh.ErrorReturnCode_2
# Command failed: python -m pythonforandroid.toolchain --color=always --storage-dir=/media/sf_PycharmProjects/settings/.buildozer/android/platform/build create --dist_name=myapp --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=kivy --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

**Edit 1**

The Project is the kivy settings example.

Project Tree:

```
.
├── android.txt
├── bin
├── buildozer.spec
├── debug.txt
├── main.py
└── my.ini
```

buildozer.spec

```
[app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = My Application

# (str) Package name
package.name = myapp

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.test

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas

# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
#source.include_patterns = assets/*,images/*.png

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 0.1

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
# version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
# version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (list) Application requirements
# comma seperated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = kivy

# (str) Custom source folders for requirements
# Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
# requirements.source.kivy = ../../kivy

# (list) Garden requirements
#garden_requirements =

# (str) Presplash of the application
#presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/presplash.png

# (str) Icon of the application
#icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon.png

# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, portrait or all)
orientation = landscape

# (list) List of service to declare
#services = NAME:ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY,NAME2:ENTRYPOINT2_TO_PY

#
# OSX Specific
#

#
# author = © Copyright Info

#
# Android specific
#

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 1

# (list) Permissions
#android.permissions = INTERNET

# (int) Android API to use
#android.api = 19

# (int) Minimum API required
#android.minapi = 9

# (int) Android SDK version to use
#android.sdk = 20

# (str) Android NDK version to use
#android.ndk = 9c

# (bool) Use --private data storage (True) or --dir public storage (False)
#android.private_storage = True

# (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ndk_path =

# (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.sdk_path =

# (str) ANT directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ant_path =

# (str) python-for-android git clone directory (if empty, it will be automatically cloned from github)
#android.p4a_dir =

# (list) python-for-android whitelist
#android.p4a_whitelist =

# (bool) If True, then skip trying to update the Android sdk
# This can be useful to avoid excess Internet downloads or save time
# when an update is due and you just want to test/build your package
# android.skip_update = False

# (str) Android entry point, default is ok for Kivy-based app
#android.entrypoint = org.renpy.android.PythonActivity

# (list) List of Java .jar files to add to the libs so that pyjnius can access
# their classes. Don't add jars that you do not need, since extra jars can slow
# down the build process. Allows wildcards matching, for example:
# OUYA-ODK/libs/*.jar
#android.add_jars = foo.jar,bar.jar,path/to/more/*.jar

# (list) List of Java files to add to the android project (can be java or a
# directory containing the files)
#android.add_src =

# (str) python-for-android branch to use, if not master, useful to try
# not yet merged features.
#android.branch = master

# (str) OUYA Console category. Should be one of GAME or APP
# If you leave this blank, OUYA support will not be enabled
#android.ouya.category = GAME

# (str) Filename of OUYA Console icon. It must be a 732x412 png image.
#android.ouya.icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/ouya_icon.png

# (str) XML file to include as an intent filters in <activity> tag
#android.manifest.intent_filters =

# (list) Android additionnal libraries to copy into libs/armeabi
#android.add_libs_armeabi = libs/android/*.so
#android.add_libs_armeabi_v7a = libs/android-v7/*.so
#android.add_libs_x86 = libs/android-x86/*.so
#android.add_libs_mips = libs/android-mips/*.so

# (bool) Indicate whether the screen should stay on
# Don't forget to add the WAKE_LOCK permission if you set this to True
#android.wakelock = False

# (list) Android application meta-data to set (key=value format)
#android.meta_data =

# (list) Android library project to add (will be added in the
# project.properties automatically.)
#android.library_references =

# (str) Android logcat filters to use
#android.logcat_filters = *:S python:D

# (bool) Copy library instead of making a libpymodules.so
#android.copy_libs = 1

#
# iOS specific
#

# (str) Path to a custom kivy-ios folder
#ios.kivy_ios_dir = ../kivy-ios

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the debug version
# Get a list of available identities: buildozer ios list_identities
#ios.codesign.debug = "iPhone Developer: <lastname> <firstname> (<hexstring>)"

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the release version
#ios.codesign.release = %(ios.codesign.debug)s


[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
log_level = 2

# (int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = False, 1 = True)
warn_on_root = 1

# (str) Path to build artifact storage, absolute or relative to spec file
# build_dir = ./.buildozer

# (str) Path to build output (i.e. .apk, .ipa) storage
# bin_dir = ./bin

#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    List as sections
#
#    You can define all the "list" as [section:key].
#    Each line will be considered as a option to the list.
#    Let's take [app] / source.exclude_patterns.
#    Instead of doing:
#
#[app]
#source.exclude_patterns = license,data/audio/*.wav,data/images/original/*
#
#    This can be translated into:
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns]
#license
#data/audio/*.wav
#data/images/original/*
#


#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Profiles
#
#    You can extend section / key with a profile
#    For example, you want to deploy a demo version of your application without
#    HD content. You could first change the title to add "(demo)" in the name
#    and extend the excluded directories to remove the HD content.
#
#[app@demo]
#title = My Application (demo)
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns@demo]
#images/hd/*
#
#    Then, invoke the command line with the "demo" profile:
#
#buildozer --profile demo android debug
```

Comment: Can you show project tree?

Comment: Informations are added to the Question (Edit 1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installing the most recent dev version (0.33dev) from github in a new (Ubuntu) vm solved the problem for me.

These are the commands from https://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-android.html:

```
cd ~
git clone https://github.com/kivy/buildozer.git
cd buildozer
sudo python2.7 setup.py install
```

Don't forget the buildozer requirements: https://buildozer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#targeting-android

Keep in mind to delete the `buildozer.spec` and `.buildozer/`. After creating the new buildozer.spec you'll have to 'enable' the line `#android.bootstrap = sdl2` and add `hostpython2` as requirement. This is due to a known Bug: https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/issues/620

Running buildozer the first time will result in some missing packages. Just install them.

If you are using shared folders with the vm, errors may occur. Just copy the files to local VM storage in such a case.