# Making android application in python using buildozer and kivy

Tags: android, python, python-2.7, buildozer

I am trying to build apk by using **buildozer**. But when I run  `buildozer -v android debug` Command to build apk I got following error

```
[INFO]:    Building python2 for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    Copying hostpython binary to targetpython folder
[INFO]:    -> running cp /home/kallz/Project/AndroidLib/examples/FaceD/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/hostpython2/deskto...(and 148 more)  
[INFO]:    Building sdl2 for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/kallz/Project/AndroidLib/examples/FaceD/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/bootstrap_builds/sdl2-python2/jni
[INFO]:    -> running ndk-build V=1
Exception in thread background thread for pid 5175:
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
 self.run()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 754, in run
self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
File "/home/kallz/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 2170, in background_thread
handle_exit_code(exit_code)
File "/home/kallz/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 1929, in fn
return self.command.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
File "/home/kallz/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 672, in handle_command_exit_code
raise exc
ErrorReturnCode_255: 

RAN: /home/kallz/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c/ndk-build V=1

STDOUT:


STDERR:


Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
"__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
exec code in run_globals
File "/home/kallz/Project/AndroidLib/examples/FaceD/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-master/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 916, in <module>
main()
File "/home/kallz/Project/AndroidLib/examples/FaceD/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-master/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 913, in main
ToolchainCL()
File "/home/kallz/Project/AndroidLib/examples/FaceD/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-master/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 514, in __init__
getattr(self, args.subparser_name.replace('-', '_'))(args)
File "/home/kallz/Project/AndroidLib/examples/FaceD/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-master/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 147, in wrapper_func
build_dist_from_args(ctx, dist, args)
File "/home/kallz/Project/AndroidLib/examples/FaceD/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-master/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 192, in build_dist_from_args
build_recipes(build_order, python_modules, ctx)
File "pythonforandroid/build.py", line 572, in build_recipes
File "/home/kallz/Project/AndroidLib/examples/FaceD/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-master/pythonforandroid/recipes/sdl2/__init__.py", line 30, in build_arch
shprint(sh.ndk_build, "V=1", _env=env)
File "pythonforandroid/logger.py", line 175, in shprint
File "/home/kallz/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 720, in next
self.wait()
File "/home/kallz/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 651, in wait
self.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
File "/home/kallz/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 672, in handle_command_exit_code
raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_255: 

RAN: /home/kallz/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c/ndk-build V=1

STDOUT:


STDERR:

# Command failed: /usr/bin/python2.7 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=myapp --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=kivy,pyjnius,hostpython2,python2,plyer --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir=/home/kallz/Project/AndroidLib/examples/FaceD/.buildozer/android/platform/build

# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

I am using python 2.7 ubuntu 17 and I already tried [Buildozer 0.32 fails to build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40360120/buildozer-0-32-fails-to-build)

I don`t know what is missing. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Downvote without any reason and no comment. :(

Comment: `# The error might be hidden in the log above this error # Please read the full log, and search for it before` -> What does the log say?

Comment: @Rightleg I already provide log in question.

Comment: Oh my bad. I hadn't understood that part of the error, I just woke up :)

Comment: I haven't been using buildozer for quite a long time, but are you sure your script runs without errors? Besides, is your manifest file alright? I don't remember how it's called, but that's the file that stores the requirements for your app, as in, the permissions to use sockets and other critical stuff

Comment: @Rightleg Buildozer use .spec file for requirments, .spec file auto make by `buildozer init` command

Comment: So? Is it alright? Does it correctly ask for the required permissions?

Comment: @Rightleg its never ask for any permission and  I run it with out `sudo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find solution myself

**Error:**

The error is in building sdl2 for armeabi-v7a ,because your current version of sdk ndk or ndk in .buildozer has incomplete downloaded or some other error

```
Building sdl2 for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/kallz/Project/AndroidLib/examples/FaceD/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/bootstrap_builds/sdl2-python2/jni
[INFO]:    -> running ndk-build V=1
Exception in thread background thread for pid 5175:
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

**Solution:**

1. delete **.buildozer** directory in the home directory for Linux( where android SDK ndk or ant installed)
2. delete **.buildozer** directory from your project or app
3. delete **buildozer.spec** file

Now start again, run following command in project directory

1. buildozer init
2. buildozer -v android debug # to make the only apk

Last command auto download sdk ndk or ant again in .buildozer in home directory